# Eclipse Ctrl+Shift+R not showing all files in the project

Tags: eclipse

When i press Ctrl+Shift+R to open the Open Resource Dialog box, the filter box does not show most of the other resource files for example.. jsp, xml etc. it works fine with all the java files.. This is happening for only this particular java project. i have refreshed the project multiple times but still no-go. I have also rebuilt the index for eclipse under workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.core by deleting the index files but to no avail.
I am using eclipse Kepler version. Any help would be great..

Comment: Did you try closing and reopening the project? Did you set a resource filter for your project in the project properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks All. Yes i had closed and opened the project many times. I have also not set any Resource filter exclusions. What i noticed was that opening any of these files for edit would set off an alert saying file was derived and would i like to edit? But on the properties for these file they were not ticked as derived but rather as Archived. So had to manually hunt for the parent folder which was making these files as derived. Also noticed that the Open Resource Dialog box has option for including Resource files "Show Derived Resources"...
This one helped me solve the problem
[Eclipse treating all the files in a project as Derived](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181808/eclipse-treating-all-the-files-in-a-project-as-derived)

Answer (score 0):

This is going to sound ridiculous...but maybe this'll help others too: **make sure your file search string is correct! You may need to begin it with a wildcard (`*`).**

I lost about 45 minutes on this as the result of user error.

I was looking for some local files named `eRCaGuy_PPM_Writer.h` and `eRCaGuy_PPM_Writer.cpp` (from [my repo here](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_PPM_Writer)). So, I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and searched for `ppm_writer`, as shown here:

[image]

Nothing! It would not find those files! No matter what I did to the files it couldn't seem to find them. I tried all sorts of things. **Then, I realized Eclipse doesn't have a fancy fuzzy search like Sublime Text 3, so I simply added an asterisk (`*`) to the front of the search, and voila! It works perfectly. *Since the "`PPM_Writer`" part of those two file names is NOT at the beginning, I must start the search with a wildcard (`*`).***

Now it works fine, as you can see here:

[image]

I've just added a note about this to my personal Eclipse setup and configuration instructions here: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/tree/master/eclipse (for my full documentation, see also the PDF and Google Drive links at the top of that page).